# Why containsKey did not find the key?

Tags: java, dictionary, key, hashmap, containskey

I have the following code:

```
payoffs2exchanges.put(point, exchange);
if (!payoffs2exchanges.containsKey(point) ) {
   game.log.fine("yes");
} else {
   game.log.fine("no");
}
```

It outputs "no". In other words, I add the key-value pair to the map, and then, immediately after that I check if the key exist and find out that it does not exist. Why?

I still have the problem with the key. The following code says every time I add a key I add a new key. And I know that it is not the case.

```
        Integer[] point = new Integer[2];
        point[0] = proposerBestScore;
        point[1] = responderBestScore;
        game.log.fine("In the getCloudOfPayoffs: found payoffs:" + point[0] + "," + point[1] + ". Exchange: " + exchange[0]+","+exchange[1]+","+exchange[2]+","+exchange[3]+","+exchange[4]);
        // With the following block we ensure that every options (pair of payoffs) is represented by exchange with minimal number of moves.
        if (!payoffs2exchanges.containsKey(point)) {
            payoffs2exchanges.put(point, exchange); 
            game.log.fine("In the getCloudOfPayoffs: this option is new. We add it to the map.");
        } else {
            game.log.fine("In the getCloudOfPayoffs: this option is old.");
            Integer[] exchangeFromMap = payoffs2exchanges.get(point);
            Integer newSum = 0;
            Integer oldSum = 0;
            for (int i=0;i<Design.nColors;i++) {
                newSum = newSum + Math.abs(exchange[i]);
                oldSum = oldSum + Math.abs(exchangeFromMap[i]);
            }
            if (newSum<oldSum) {
                game.log.fine("In the getCloudOfPayoffs: the new exchange is better than the old one.");
                payoffs2exchanges.put(point, exchange);
            }
        }
```

Comment: What class is `point`? Custom class? What class is `payoffs2exchanges`?

Comment: Added an answer addressing your update.

Comment: @aioobe, sorry for these manipulations with the question. I put it back. So, you answer is useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're using an `Integer[]` as key in the map. This is a bad thing, since **Java arrays don't implement `equals` and `hashCode` as you might expect.** See this example:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer[] arr1 = { 1, 2 };
        Integer[] arr2 = { 1, 2 };

        System.out.println(arr1.equals(arr2));
        System.out.println(arr1.hashCode() + " / " + arr2.hashCode());
    }
}
```

On my computer it prints:

```
false
1476323068 / 535746438
```

My recommendation is to create a custom `Point` class that properly overrides `equals` and `hashCode` (or possibly reuse `java.awt.Point` if you think that makes sense).

Comment: does it mean that containsKey does not work if I use integer array as a key?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Maps in general rely heavily on the `equals` method, and when it comes to for instance `HashMap` the `hashCode` is important as well.

Comment: but can I still use `somHashMap.get(key)` if key is an integer array?

Comment: No. The `get` method would call `key.hashCode()` to figure out in which bucket to look for the value associated with `key`. If the hash value of `key` doesn't correspond to the hash value of the key used when inserting the element, the hash map will simply (most likely) look for the value in the wrong bucket.

Answer (score 6):

It *is* doing the right thing. `containsKey` returns `true`, the `!` operator negates it to `false`, and so it outputs `no` (the else clause).

Answer (score 0):

Look at your code :) it prints `no` if the map actually contains the key...